# Does the North American island of Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon still hold a strategic advantage for France?

Tags: france, canada, territory

Saint-Pierre-et-Miquelon has had strategic significance at various eras in its history, mostly as fishing grounds and a geographical bargaining chip between France and England[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Saint_Pierre_and_Miquelon). It also played a role in World War II and was [nearly invaded by Canada at that time.](https://journals.lib.unb.ca/index.php/acadiensis/article/view/10684/11369)

I was unable to find much information regarding its current strategic importance, however. The fishing industry still exists but I am wondering if there is any specific bonus advantage for France to hold these islands beyond the fact of caring for the French population there.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has no strategic importance. With a population of 6000, no significant territorial waters, no notable oil or gas deposits, and minimal economic activity. It has no capability for handling military ships or aircraft. It might theoretically be used as an airbase in the unlikely event that Canada was not sufficiently cooperative to lend its own (much better) airbases but not uncooperative enough to prevent that.

Comment: What are the alternatives to holding these islands? As long as the population doesn't strongly demand independence or joining Canada (and Canada willing in the latter case) the island will just stay French because it is French now.

Comment: You can judge its importance by seeing what is sited there. Not sure how up to date [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Pierre_and_Miquelon) is, but there's apparently a patrol boat (a former fishing vessel) and some gendarmes. No military base, limited transport links, not much industry or commerce, most people employed in the public sector. The OP doesn't specify what they mean by strategic importance (maybe it has some symbolic value), but it's hardly either a militarily or economically important site.

Comment: Yeah it seems the conclusion is "no" but I was asking to see if I might have missed something as I know I have a limited understanding of these things.